# Two SELECT statements as two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

This seems like a simple query, but I'm struggling with it.

Here's a sampling of my data.

```
user_id  dated
463      2016-01-01
463      2016-01-02
1456     2016-01-01
1456     2016-01-02
1398     2015-12-01
1398     2015-12-02
```

I want to get the number of unique users in two different time periods. Here are the queries I want to get a combined output from in a single row, and two columns.

```
-- 60
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tld.user_id)) count_active_users_60
FROM table tld
WHERE tld.dated BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL '60 days') AND (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days')

-- 30
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tld.user_id)) count_active_users_30
FROM table tld
WHERE tld.dated >= NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'
```

I'd like an output that looks like this:

```
count_active_users_60    count_active_users_30
1                        2
```

I've been messing with various CASE statements, and sub-selects, but the distinct clause is throwing me off.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(rar.user_id))
FROM 
(
SELECT user_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN tld.dated BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL '60 days') AND (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS count_active_users_60,
COUNT(CASE WHEN tld.dated >= NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS count_active_users_30
FROM testing_login_duration tld
GROUP BY user_id
) rar;
```

Comment: You can remove these redundant parentheses for distinct to make code much clearer, i.e. `COUNT(DISTINCT tld.user_id)`.

Comment: You are doing case expressions, not case statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tld.dated BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL '60 days') AND (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days')
                           THEN tld.user_id
                       END) count_active_users_60,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tld.dated >= NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'
                           THEN tld.user_id
                       END) count_active_users_30
FROM table tld
WHERE tld.dated >= NOW() - INTERVAL '60 days';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I wouldn't have thought of that!