# posgresql selecting two different data as two columns from one column

Tags: postgresql

I need to select two id's from `stockcurrent` as two different columns (id1,id2), first where points.id = '244' and second where points.id ='191'. But result facing last `where` clause and filling only one column based on that statement.

I think I've faced a similar problem as in that case: [Two SELECT statements as two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858202/two-select-statements-as-two-columns;)

The only difference is that in the case above his last `where` clause is in range but mine is not. In my opinion, it is the reason why my statement is not working:

```sql
select
(case when po.id='244' then st.id end) id1,
 (case when po.id='191' then st.id end) id2
from stockcurrent st
inner join points po on po.id = st.point
where po.id ='244';
```

My result:
[image: first_result]
Expected result:
[image]

So I need to find a solution to fill both columns with id's not only one which in that case giving me the result(s) of '244'. Thanks in advance.
Example of `stockcurrent` table:

```
+-------+-------+
|  id   | point |
+-------+-------+
| 23414 |   191 |
| 12493 |   191 |
| 16121 |   170 |
| 24325 |   191 |
| 51232 |   244 |
| 11255 |   244 |
| 56572 |   244 |
| 16123 |   170 |
+-------+-------+
```

Example of `points` table:

```
+-----+------+------+
| id  | comp | type |
+-----+------+------+
| 191 |   96 |    2 |
| 307 |   96 |    1 |
| 244 |   97 |    0 |
| 311 |   98 |    0 |
| 170 |  109 |    0 |
+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: If you join on po.id = st.point then there can be only one point.id value per line in stoccurrent, so I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: `where po.id in ('244', '191');`

Comment: @bobflux ok, maybe join is incorrect, and the whole code that I've tried is in the wrong direction but is there any other way to achieve what I want? Maybe subqueries or unions, unfortunately, my confidence in SQL is very poor.  I need to create one select statement with two columns as a result, one for id where point is 244, and the second id for 191.

Comment: @adrianKlaver your solution worked well, actually, it solved the problem. I was guessing why your solution is giving me empty [null] fields but then realized that it is just because not every id that I needed to find, has appropriate point. That is why I was thinking that your answer is not correct. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
select
(case when po.id='244' then st.id end) id1,
 (case when po.id='191' then st.id end) id2
from stockcurrent st
inner join points po on po.id = st.point
where po.id in ('244', '191');
```